# Assign array values in php accordingly

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I have 3 arrays:

```
$firstArray =  Array([0] => 33 [1] => 34)
$secongArray = Array([0] => 71300 [1] => 72300)
$thirdArray =  Array([0] => 71300 [1] => 72300 [2] => 234234)
```

How do I make it something like this,

```
$outputArray = array
   (
   array(33,71300,71300),
   array(34,72300,72300),
   array(NULL,NULL,234234),
   //.....
   );
```

Comment: Are you trying to make those three arrays into a single 2-dimesional array, and then transpose it?

Comment: Yes, @MarkBaker I actually have (33,34) (71300,72300) and (71300,72300, 234234) as variables then I used explode to convert them into arrays. And now I have these arrays and need to convert them into a 2 dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$firstArray =  array(33, 34);
$secondArray = array(71300, 72300);
$thirdArray =  array(71300, 72300, 234234);

$outputArray = call_user_func_array(
    'array_map',
    array_merge(
        array(NULL),
        array(
            $firstArray,
            $secondArray,
            $thirdArray
        )
    )
);
var_dump($outputArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$max = max(count($firstArray),count($secongArray),count($thirdArray));
$outputArray = array();
for($i==0;$i<$max;$i++) {
    //test unset values
    if(!isset($firstArray[$i])) $firstArray[$i] = null;
    if(!isset($secongArray[$i])) $secongArray[$i] = null;
    if(!isset($thirdArray[$i])) $thirdArray[$i] = null;

    $outputArray[] = array($firstArray[$i],$secongArray[$i],$thirdArray[$i]);
}
```